# Is there an Equivalent for @InitBinder in Jersey JAX -RS?

Tags: java, rest, jersey-2.0

I am building a new rest API resource which I have a @queryParam which can be either "CSV" or "XLS". I made this using an enum class then I implemented this "@DefaultValue("xls") @QueryParam(FORMAT_FILTER) FormatExport format"
Googling I realized that is necessary to implement a @InitBinder, although InitBinder is part of Spring, not Jersey.
Is there an equivalent.

```
//1. Enum class.
    public enum FormatExport
    {
        json("xls"),
        scv("csv");

      private String label;

      private FormatExport(String value)
      {
        this.label = value;
      }

      public static FormatExport fromValue(String value)
      {
        for(FormatExport format : values())
        {
           if(format.label.compareToIgnoreCase(value) == 0)
           {
               return format;
           }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown value type: " + value );
    }
    }

//2. resource

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/elements")
    public Response findElements(
        @DefaultValue("json") @QueryParam(FORMAT_FILTER) FormatExport format)
    {
        switch (format)
        {
            case json:
                /* Code */
            case scv:
                /* Code */
            default:
                break;
        }
}

//I found this

    public class QuestionCategoryConverter extends PropertyEditorSupport{

     public void setAsText(final String text) throws IllegalArgumentException 
    {
            setValue(QuestionCategory.fromValue(text));
        }

    }


    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(final WebDataBinder webdataBinder) {
        webdataBinder.registerCustomEditor(QuestionCategory.class, new 
        QuestionCategoryConverter());
}


//This used a spring annotation
```